# Google Maps v3 API: How to update markers' location when changing route by dragging?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying the following out, based on the example from [GoogleMapsv3APIExample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable):

- I have a route from A to B with some markers:
  [image]
- I modify the route by dragging "a transitional waypoint" (shown by a white circle)
- I want the markers to be updated to the new route

I adapted the linked example in this **[gist](https://gist.github.com/rmihalyi/9722174#file-testdragroute)**:

- on lines 37-39 I add a listener for the **directions_changed** event
- in **recalculateMarkers**, I set all markers to null and place them again on the map
- it seems that **directionsDisplay.directions** still contains the old route (before dragging)
- the result I get is this: [image]

Any suggestions ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in `directions_changed` event: *This event is fired when the rendered directions change, either when a new DirectionsResult is set or when the user finishes dragging a change to the directions path.*

When `calcRoute()` finishes there are two sets of markers created: one from `recalculateMarkers()` and the other from `calcRoute()`.

Event listener has to be moved to `calcRoute()` and to be set up in case of route success:

```
function calcRoute() {

    var request = {
        origin: 'Sydney, NSW',
        destination: 'Broken Hill, NSW',
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            showSteps(response);

            google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
                console.log('directions_changed');
                recalculateMarkers();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gezij/1/edit).